# Calling variable ID from one function onto another function (nodejs) (mongoose)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, function, schema

I'm new at coding and nodejs and I believe this problem may be just my lack of nodejs/coding experience.
The code is posted below and for more information I have posted the Github file

I am trying to call the object id from one function into another function so I can relate the parent and child functions.

Specifically (in the file **users.js**) I am trying to calling the **newUser** variable from the function **router.post("/register", (req, res)** to the function **router.post("/registerCar", (req, res)** but whenever I try to call the **newUser** variable in the **registerCar** function, it seems to empty. Even if I call **User._id**, that also seems to be empty.

I am trying to figure out how to call the object id of **newUser** into **newCar**.

Things I have tried:

- I have tried to add the **router.post("/registerCar", (req, res)** into the **router.post("/register", (req, res)** but whenever I try to submit the car registration form it says "method POST registerCar cannot be found" or something of the sort
- Made **newUser** into a global variable, but for some reason I wasn't able to call it in **router.post("/registerCar", (req, res)**
- Tried callback parameter in **router.post("/register", (req, res)** function but that didn't really work (although I could have been doing it wrong)
- I have tried adding **_id: Schema.Types.ObjectId;** into User.js and Car.js but it gives me an error "Error [MongooseError]: document must have an _id before saving at new MongooseError". I tried researching a solution for this but nothing came up.

I know this is a lot, but I'm trying to expand my coding skills and I've been stuck at this for two days. If you guys can help me out I would greatly appreciate it.

*___________________________________________________________________________________________________*

```
// User.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;


const UserSchema =  new mongoose.Schema({
   name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
  carType: [{ 
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
    ref: 'Car' 
  }]
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);    
module.exports = User;
```

*___________________________________________________________________________________________________*

```
//Car.js

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
 const UserModel =  new mongoose.Schema({
    carMake: {
    type: String,
    require: true,
  },
  carModel: {
    type: String,
    require: true,
  },
  carid: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
    ref: 'User'
  }]
});

const Car = mongoose.model('Car', UserModel);
module.exports = Car;
```

*___________________________________________________________________________________________________*

```
//users.js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const passport = require("passport");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// User model
const User = require("../models/User");

//Cars model
const Car = require("../models/Car");

//Login
router.get("/login", (req, res) => res.render("login"));

//Register Page
router.get("/register", (req, res) => res.render("register"));

//test page
router.get("/test", (req, res) => res.render("test"));

//registerCar Page
router.get("/registerCar", (req, res) => res.render("registerCar"));

// Register Handle
router.post("/register", (req, res) => {
  const { name, email, password, password2 } = req.body;
  let errors = [];

  // Check required fields
  if (!name || !email || !password || !password2) {
    errors.push({ msg: "Please fill in all fields." });
  }

  // Check passwords match
  if (password != password2) {
    errors.push({ msg: "Passwords do not match." });
  }

  // Check pw length
  if (password.length < 6) {
    errors.push({ msg: "Password should be longer than 6 characters." });
  }

  // Issue present
  if (errors.length > 0) {
    res.render("register", {
      errors,
      name,
      email,
      password,
      password2,
    });
  } else {
    // Validation passed
    User.findOne({ email: email }).then((user, callback) => {
      if (user) {
        // User exists
        errors.push({ msg: "Email is already registered" });
        res.render("register", {
          errors,
          name,
          email,
          password,
          password2,
        });
      } else {
        const newUser = new User({
          name,
          email,
          password,
        });

        // Hash Password
        bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) =>
          bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            //Set password to hashed
            newUser.password = hash;
            //Save user
            newUser
              .save()
              .then((user) => {
                req.flash(
                  "success_msg",
                  "You are now registered. Please log in."
                );
                res.redirect("/users/login");
              })
              .catch((err) => console.log(err));
          })
        );
      }
    });
  }
});

// Login Handle
router.post("/login", (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate("local", {
    successRedirect: "/dashboard",
    failureRedirect: "/users/login",
    failureFlash: true,
  })(req, res, next);
});

//Logout Handle
router.get("/logout", (req, res) => {
  req.logout();
  req.flash("success_msg", "You are logged out");
  res.redirect("/users/login");
});

// Car registration Handle
router.post("/registerCar", (req, res) => {
  const { carMake, carModel, carid } = req.body;
  let errors = [];

  const newCar = new Car({
    carMake,
    carModel,
    carid, //want to call User ID over here  
  });

  newCar
    .save()
    .then((car) => {
      console.log(newCar._id);
      res.redirect("/dashboard");
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
});

module.exports = router;
```

*___________________________________________________________________________________________________*

github link: https://github.com/AamirAshraf96/carGarage

Comment: If you want user_id from the user, then you should be including it in the body of the request. RESTful API is stateless, so you should not have to store at the backend, which user is logged in.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by RESTful API is stateless?

Comment: https://restfulapi.net/ This page offers good explanation

Comment: So the problem with calling it in the body is that it doesn't retrieve the user's value that just registered.